# Copying header of a .pgm file

Tags: c, header, scanf, printf, pgm

I have been getting an error when trying to copy the header of a pgm to another. could someone please tell me where i'm wrong?

```
    FILE *infile;
infile = fopen(fin, "rb");
fscanf(infile, "%s %d %d %d\n",&type,&u,&v,&depth);

FILE *outfile;
outfile = fopen(fout, "wb");    
fprintf(outfile, "%s %d %d %d\n",&type,u,v,depth);
```

Comment: Do you think that actually telling us about the error would make it too easy to answer the question ;) ?

Comment: true.... ok when i compile again ill post the error lol

Comment: You should also include the variables declarations. 
It seems that `&type` in the last line should be `type` instead.